# PHP CURL PUT function not working

Tags: php, curl

I want to issue a put request to a java service where it's not working, even its not showing any descriptive errors as well.

```
include './rootURL.php';

$header = array("Content-Type: application/json");

$prop_key = 'prop key value';

$data = array();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$id = $data["id"];

$url = $rooturl.'cancelBooking/'.$prop_key.'/'.$id;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 75);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

error_log($result);            
echo $result;
```

the above is my php script and the URL hear is working the way i want it, i don't think there is anything wrong in the URL. services also working fine i tested it with swagger and its working fine.

When i log the error, i received something like this.

```
[Thu Jun 02 12:56:38.813140 2016] [:error] [pid 6290] [client127.0.0.1:39198] , referer: http://localhost/adminPanel/booking.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not putting your data anywhere.

I have a service which allows to put data and this code is the one I use

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$return = curl_exec($ch);
```

This line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));` contains my data I submit but I can't find this line in your code.

Checked your code again and found `$prop_key = 'prop key value';` which you're using in the URL `$url = $rooturl.'cancelBooking/'.$prop_key.'/'.$id;`

Change the url to `$url = $rooturl.'cancelBooking/'.urlencode($prop_key).'/'.$id;`
 since the whitespaces might be a problem.

Comment: its not actually woriking since i dont have anything to post in its body